# New JDK for old java app

Tags: java, tomcat, web-applications

I have a rather old java web app, which uses servlet spec version 2.3. I use struts 1.0, jsf 1.0 there, etc. This app is running on tomcat 6.0.13. Java version in 1.7. But, I want to upgrade java there. May I install jdk 1.8+ there? I tried, but it began complaining on UI part incompatibility, etc. How to install in there?

Comment: *"... but it began complaining on UI part incompatibility ..."* - You are going to have to explain your problem better than that.  We need a clear and detailed description of your problem if you want us to help you.

Comment: thanks, but I need to know is it possible at all. Thanks

Comment: Yes.  It is possible to run Tomcat 6 on Java 8.

Comment: thank you, I will update this question when done with testing next week. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After 4 days of running tomcat 6 and Java 8 I can say that there are 2 big issues which (thanks God) I have managed to fix.

**Make sure all browsers which are using your web app has TLS enabled**

Starting from certain update of JDK 7 java required TLS to be enabled in the browser, for example I had a trouble with clients which used IE6. The same is true for JDK8

**Make sure you don't have any scriptlets in your application or they are compatible with java8**

Tomcat compiles all your jsps to the special classes, and if you have in your code a construction like:

```
<% Set set=myHashMap.entrySet().blabla%>
```

you will get an exception which says that it can't understand the .class file structure, because tomcat is trying to use special framework (jasper?), which tries to parse the .class file of compiled jsp page. I moved scriptlets to the appropriate backing beans and it works ok. Please edit this answer if I was incorrect in tech description.